# WELD-00143 Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies

Tags: java, junit, ejb, javabeans, cdi

Using WeldJUnit4Runner and getting error message:

> Exception 0 : org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:
>   WELD-001443: Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies. Dependency
>   path:
>     - Managed Bean [class com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestService]
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default],

Any known solution for this problem in Weld?

> More error message: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>                   at com.my.own.WeldJUnit4Runner.createTest(WeldJUnit4Runner.java:18)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
>                   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>                   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>                   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>                   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception
>   List with 102 exceptions: Exception 0 :
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001443: Pseudo
>   scoped bean has circular dependencies. Dependency path:
>     - Managed Bean [class com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestService]
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestService.listener,
>     - Managed Bean [class com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestListener]
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestListener.clientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestRepository,
>     - Managed Bean [class com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.repositories.ClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestRepository]
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
>     - [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @ClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestCache private
>   com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.repositories.ClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestRepository.clientCallPriorizedAcceptRequestCache,
>     - Producer Method [RemoteCache] with qualifiers
>   [@ClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestCache @Any] declared as
>   [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces
>   @ClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestCache public
>   com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestService.getClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestRemoteCache()],
>     - Managed Bean [class com.my.own.bounded_contexts.client.cache.cacheClientCommPriorizedAcceptRequestService]
>   with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
>                   at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.reallyValidatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:897)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weld complies with the specification in this respect.

From the [CDI spec](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injection_el_resolution), section 5:

> The container is required to support circularities in the bean
>   dependency graph where at least one bean participating in every
>   circular chain of dependencies has a normal scope, as defined in
>   Normal scopes and pseudo-scopes. The container is not required to
>   support circular chains of dependencies where every bean participating
>   in the chain has a pseudo-scope.

Try to get rid of the dependency cycle in your application, or at least give a normal scope to one of the beans involved.